# HTTP request not hitting controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, http

I currently have a problem where I send an asynchronous ajax request to a .NET controller in order to start a database search. This request makes it to the server which kicks off the search and immediately (less than a second) replies to the callback with a search ID, at which point I begin sending ajax requests every 10 seconds to check if the search has finished. This method works fine, and has been tested successfully with multiple users sending simultaneous requests.

If I send a second search request from the same user before the first search is finished, this call will not make it to the controller endpoint until after the first search has completed, which can take up to a minute. I can see the request leave chrome (or FF/IE) in the dev tools, and using Fiddler as a proxy I can see the request hit the machine that the application is running on, however it will not hit the breakpoint on the first line of the endpoint until after the first call returns.

At the point this call is blocking, there are typically up to 3 pending requests from the browser. Does IIS or the .NET architecture have some mechanism that is queuing my request? Or if not, what else would be between the request leaving the proxy and entering the controller? I'm at a bit of a loss for how to debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the issue. It turns out that despite my endpoint being defined asynchronously, ASP.NET controllers by default synchronize by session. So while my endpoints were able to be executed simultaneously across sessions, within the same session it would only allow one call at a time. I was able to fix the issue by setting the controller SessionState attribute to Read Only, allowing my calls to come through without blocking.

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```